# Why is the order of execution inversed in this bash script?

Tags: bash, ssh, execution, tail

I have this script :

```
ssh -T user@$123.456.789.123 <<EOF

    cd www

    var=$(tail index.htm)

    echo $var

EOF
```

What I thought it should do is :

1. Connect to the server through *SSH*,
2. then change to the folder *www*,
3. then store the *tail* of *index.htm* into the variable *var*
4. and finally *echo* the result.

Instead it seems that *tail* is executed before the change of folder, and thus doesn't find the *index.htm* file.

I've tried with different commands, and each time it seems the result from command substitution I'm trying to store into a variable is executed right after the SSH connexion is opened, before any other piece of script.

What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `$(...)` is being expanded locally, before the contents of the here document are passed to `ssh`. To send literal text to the remote server, quote the here document delimiter.

```
ssh -T user@$123.456.789.123 <<'EOF'
    cd www
    var=$(tail index.htm)
    echo "$var"
EOF
```

(Also, quote the expansion of `$var` to protect any embedded spacing from the shell.)

Answer (score 2):

The `tail` is running in the bash script on your local machine, not on the remote host.  The substitution is getting made before you even execute the `ssh` command.

Your script can be replaced with simply:

```
ssh -T user@$123.456.789.123 tail www/index.htm
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to send those commands to the remote server, you can write

```
ssh -T user@$123.456.789.123 'cd www && var=$(tail index.htm) && echo $var'
```

Note that conditioning the next command on the result of the previous allows SSH to return a meaningful return code. In your heredoc, whatever happens (e.g. `tail` fails), SSH will return with $?=0 because `echo` will not fail.

Another option is to create a script there and launch it with ssh.

Comment: The `$(...)` will still be expanded locally, just like with the unquoted here document.